# Reference a passed in parameter in JQuery JSP

Tags: java, jquery, jsp

I'm trying to reference a parameter passed from Java code over to a JSP in JQuery. Here is what I have so far:

Java:

```
HashMap<String, Object> result = new HashMap<String, Object>();
result.put("minumumAge", admin.getAge());
return new ModelAndView("home", result);
```

JSP:

```
int i = $("#minumumAge").val();
var dateOffset = (24*60*60*1000) * i;
```

However, I can't get the minimumAge value into the i variable. Please let me know what the correct syntax is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
<%
    int minAge = (Integer)request.getAttribute("minumumAge");
%>
var i = <%=minAge%>;
var dateOffset = (24*60*60*1000) * i;
```

Comment: This is saying minumumAge cant be resolved to a variable

Comment: you have to get the attribute from the request, i updated my answer

Comment: Thanks, looks like you have to cast it to the desired return type e.g. (Integer) request.getAttribute("minumumAge");